# Cant center a div within a screen

Tags: html, css, center

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<!-- Social Media Icons -->
<div id="sm1"><a href="/"><img src="images/facebook.png" height=40 width=40></img></a>
</div>
<div id="sm2"><a href="/"><img src="images/twitter.png" height=40 width=40></img><a></div>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"</img></div>
    <div id="slogan"><blockquote>Insert slogan here...</blockquote></div>
    <!-- Slideshow -->
    <div id="slideshow"></div>
    <!-- Box -->
    <div id="box1" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box4" class="boxes"></div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footerimg">
        <center>
            <img src="images/facebook.png" height=20 width=20></img>
            <img src="images/twitter.png" height=20 width=20></img>
            </div>
            <div id="footertext">
            &copy; 2014 My Designs. All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
    </div>
        </body>
```

CSS Code:

```
            /*Tags*/
        body {
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:100px;
        }
        blockquote {
            font-style:italic;
        }
        /*Div Id*/
        #logo {
            position:absolute;
            width:150px;
            height:40px;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
        #sm1 {
            position:absolute;
            width:40px;
            height:40px;
            margin-top:20px;
            margin-left:650px;
        }
        #sm2 {
            position:absolute;
            width:40px;
            height:40px;
            margin-top:20px;
            margin-left:710px;
        }
        #slideshow {
            width:750px;
            height:400px;
            background-color:purple;
            margin-top:80px;
        }
        #box1 {
            background-color:aqua;
        }
        #box2 {
            margin-left:190px;
            background-color:fuchsia;
        }
        #box3 {
            margin-left:380px;
            background-color:gray;
        }
        #box4 {
            margin-left:570px;
            background-color:green;
        }
         #footer {

         width:750px;
         height:50px;
         background-color:olive;
         position:absolute;
         margin-top:140px;
         text-align:center;
         font-family:sans-serif;
     }
        }
        #slogan {
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:120px;
            margin-top:15px;
        }
        #footerimg {
            margin-top:5px;
        }
        #footertext {
            color:white;
        }
        /*Div Class*/
        .boxes {
            margin-top:10px;
            position:absolute;
            width:180px;
            height:120px;
        }
```

I'm trying to center all the code within `<body></body>` and `<footer></footer>`. I've tried searching for solutions but they haven't seemed to work out. And maybe, if there are people that are experts, could they maybe fix up my code so it doesn't look bad?

Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/prL6doct/

Comment: The place to go for coding style tips is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll go and check it out. Do you have a section of that website where you would recommend me to go to first?

Comment: Just start searching for questions about best practices e.g. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60623/checking-css-code-for-best-practices-when-mimicking

Comment: somthing unrelated, but your `<center>` is not closed. Also HTML5 doesnt support the center tag anymore. (it was already with the 4.0 already overrated and could be modified with css. So use instead in your css style `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 0):

please change this **width:750px;**

```
 #footer {

        width:750px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:olive;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:140px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:sans-serif;
    }
```

It worked for me , Hope this is what you have wanted.

Edit: please see this http://jsfiddle.net/sheralam/b2mzrgxo/ , hope this was what you wanted.

Comment: That only changed the footer. I was wanting to center the divs within the screen.

Comment: ahh..then you will need to change some more things. as you have used absolute positioning. I would suggest to redesign your code

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/sheralam/b2mzrgxo/, hope this was what you have wanted

Comment: Well would you be able to remake it so I can know what I need to change to make it actually work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do lots of changes.

[Here is the updated code.](http://jsfiddle.net/prL6doct/2/)

Remove `position: absolute` for `.footer`, `.boxes` and `body`

And remove margin-left for all `#boxes`

And add `.wrapper` to make the content center.

give `margin: 0 auto` to `.footer`

Answer (score 0):

to center the content of a page you can wrap all the content after the body tag in a div, usually called a container div ( with id=container, but you can give any id you want). then apply following style to the container div

```
 #container{
   margin:0 auto;
   width:    ; // apply any suitable width till the layout is centered
   }
```